# CSS overriding with classes

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I've been reading through the documentation for Material UI's Overrides because I am trying to change each radio buttons color and it's just not clicking (mentally). So if I use Material UI's boilerplate for radio buttons how do I change the colors individually? And I appreciate the help! But if you could breakdown what you are doing for me. This is an area I struggle with so I want to know what is going on. Thank you so much!=]

https://codesandbox.io/s/w0k7j863x8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `className="classForIndividualRadio"` to `Radio` in demo.js

add style to your index.html or an external css file.

```
 <style>  
.classForIndividualRadio{
 color:green;
  }

</style>
```

code: https://codesandbox.io/s/8yq6yllj2l

Comment: This works, I dont know why I didnt think of doing this.